# Show that $P\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n \text{ converges}\right)=0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $({X_n})_n$ be a sequence of iid r.v.’s such that $P(X_1 \neq 0)>0.$ Show that
>   $$P\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n \text{ converges}\right)=0$$

I am struggling this problem. Please help me out.

Comment: Please show some proof of your struggle.

Comment: I tried to use Borel Cantelli lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P(|X_n|>0)>0$ there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $P(|X_n|=m^{-1})>0$.
By Borel-Cantelli we have 
$$
P(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{|X_n|>m^{-1} \} )=1.
$$
Thus,
$$
P(\sum_{n=0}^\infty X_n \text{ converges})
\le P((X_n) \text{ converges to $0$}) =0.
$$